# Insecure world writable dir /Users/username in PATH, mode 040777 when running Ruby commands

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions, path

When I run Ruby commands like `gem -v` I get this error:

> /Users/kristoffer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/gem:4:
>   warning: Insecure world writable dir
>   /Users/kristoffer in PATH, mode 040777
>
> 1.6.2

First of all I don't understand what this means. /Users/kristoffer is not in my path according to `echo $PATH`. The result of `echo $PATH` is:

> /Users/kristoffer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/kristoffer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/Users/kristoffer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/Users/kristoffer/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

As you can see, the PATH is pretty clean. Just the default path + what RVM added.

I've seen the other posts similar to this where the recommended way to solve the issue is to run `chmod go-w path/to/folder`

However, I'm pretty sure that it's a bad idea to make my Home folder non-writeable, right? I've repaired permissions using Disk Utility and it didn't find anything wrong with the permissions on my Home folder.

Any idea of what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: I think you definitely don't want your home dir world-writeable.  Running the chmod would be a good idea.  Since your home directory is world writeable, any folders under that (several of which are in your path) could be modified, so maybe that is why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Your home folder should only be writable by you, not by anyone else.  The reason gem is complaining about this is that you have folders in your PATH that are inside your (insecure) home folder, and that means that anyone who wants to could hack you by renaming/moving your .rvm folder and replacing it with an impostor.

To fix your home folder, run `chmod go-w /Users/kristoffer`.  If there are any other insecure folders on the way to anything in your PATH, you should fix them similarly.

BTW, the reason that Disk Utility didn't repair this is that it only repairs files installed as part of the OS (see [Apple's KB article on the subject](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1452)).  There is an option to repair home folder permissions if you boot from the install DVD and run Password Reset from the Utilities menu, but I'm not sure if it resets the permissions themselves or just ownership.

Comment: Ah, thanks! That fixed the problem.

I was worried about running `chmod go-w` because I thought it removed write permissions for all users, including me.

Comment: Shouldn't this have a -R for recursive?

Comment: @Mike: No, that would break any folders that're supposed to be writable by others (mainly ~/Public/Drop Box).  If there are any other inappropriately-writable folders inside his home, they will have to be fixed as well, but `-R` would be (slightly) overkill.

Comment: I run ```chmod go-w /Users/[my name]```, but I got the msg ```chmod: cannot access '/Users/[my name]': No such file or directory```

Comment: @Ckt22 You need to use whatever the actual path to your home directory is. You can use `echo ~` to print the path, or just use `chmod go-w ~` and it should take care of it for you.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I run ```sudo chmod go-w ~ /home/keaton```, and then run ```rails s```, the result is still stuck in the same problem: ```/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/app_rails_loader.rb:39: warning: Insecure world writable dir /mnt/c in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/bin/ruby2.5: warning: shebang line ending with \r may cause problems
Your Ruby version is 2.5.1, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.6```

Comment: @Ckt22 According to the error message, the problem isn't the permissions on your home directory, it's `/mnt/c` that's the problem. This sounds like you're using Ubuntu under Windows, which I'm not familiar with. Also, the shebang error indicates you have at least one file with Windows-style line endings (rather than Unix-style), which is likely to cause trouble.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Yes, I using Ubuntu under Windows, What file should I modify or fix?

Comment: After I changed the default Ruby version of RVM to the version required by the repo, the problem was solved. unknown reason.

Answer (score 14):

I kept getting this in my prompt.

[image]

I couldn't get it quite right with my command prompt but this ended up working.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot!  It works.  When I migrated my HDD to the SSD somehow "everyone" can Read&Write my user folder.  Switching everyone to No Access fixes the warning.

Answer (score 6):

```
chmod 755 /Users/<username>
```

Should fix the problem...

Comment: I run ```chmod 755 /Users/[my name]```, but I got the msg ```chmod: cannot access '/Users/[my name]': No such file or directory```

Answer (score 5):

Recently this just happened to me and it has to do with a bug in upgrading to Mac OSX 10.9.3. Looks like the upgrade changes the permissons to the User folder. Here's an explanation and a fix:

http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2014/05/16/users-folder-being-hidden-with-itunes-11-2-installed-and-find-my-mac-enabled/

Answer (score 1):

it says that the directory Users/username is insecure, you can fix that by running
sudo chmod go-w Users/username

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Like user2952657, I got this warning with vagrant up after upgrading to OSX 10.9.3. Updating iTunes to 11.2.1 was all I needed to do to get the warning to stop.