# CocoaPod Mac Install Error

Tags: cocoapods

i want to install CocoaPods in Mac but all the time when i asked to install it i'm getting following statement please find below it.thanks for your advance

```
Last login: Fri Jul 18 11:45:00 on ttys000
venushkas-MacBook-Pro:~ venushka$ gem install cocoapods
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/universal-darwin13/rbconfig.rb:213: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr in PATH, mode 040777
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific warning you've provided should not affect the installation of CocoaPods. If you'd like to silence it there are solutions to it from many other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192003/insecure-world-writable-dir-users-username-in-path-mode-040777-when-running-ru).

Just based on what you pasted you probably need to install CocoaPods with:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Because your using the system version of Ruby.